# Power bi client filter with multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have power bi client filter code below:

```
const basicFilter: pbi.models.IBasicFilter = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
  target: {
    table: "Store",
    column: "Count"
  },
  operator: "In",
  values: [1,2,3,4],
  filterType: pbi.models.FilterType.BasicFilter
}
```

in my scenario a table can have multiple columns, so if I want to filter by multiple columns of the table then how can I do? In the above code only one column like Count is working, but how to configure for multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a filter for each of your conditions and pass an array with all your filters in [ReportConfiguration.filters](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) property:

```
var embedConfig = {
  ...
  filters: [basicFilter1, basicFilter2, filter3]
};
```

or to [report.setFilters](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters) method:

```
report.setFilters([basicFilter1, basicFilter2, filter3])
  .catch(errors => {
    // Handle error
  });
```